# How does internet explorer gets its favorites?

Tags: internet-explorer, bookmarks

Looks like there are two ways for Internet Explorer to keep its favorites list: in "Windows/Favorites" folder and in registry "HKCU/Software/Microsoft/Internet Explorer/Main/FavouritesEntries".

The information there seems duplicated. I would like to know, how does internet explorer builds his favorites list? He prefers registry settings or folder settings? And how does it handle the situation, when registry list does not match folder list?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think "HKCU/Software/Microsoft/Internet Explorer/Main/FavouritesEntries" location has default IE bookmarks and user bookmarks are stored in Windows/Favorites folder. So IE would use combination of both this list to build favorites when IE is loaded.

Comment: My experiments show, that explorer seems to ignore the registry. I add some entries to the registry, but I don't see them in my Favorite list in IE...

Answer (score 0):

It also takes contents from the folders specified in "Favorites" key in these registry locations:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Explorer\Shell folders
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Explorer\User Shell folders
HKEY_USERS\.default\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Explorer\Shell folders
HKEY_USERS\.default\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Explorer\User Shell folders
```